# Show Custom Post From Logged In Author

Tags: posts, users

I have a custom home page set up so soon as users log in they see an overview of their account. I want to show them all of their own posts but im having trouble and can only get it to show current published posts to everyone. I need to show only the logged in user their own post

I am also having issues with the categories showing all categories in the post type and not just what the post has. What do i need to use rather than wp_list_categories to just list cats attached to post?

```
<?php 
 query_posts( array( 'post_author' => $current_user->ID, 'post_status' => 'publish' , 'post_type' => array(    'user_lists' )  ) ); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php echo '<div class="tr"><div class="td style2">';
  echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">'; the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at
  <?php the_time('g:i a'); echo '</a>';
   echo '</div><div class="td">'; 
  echo wp_list_categories('taxonomy=list_type&type=user_lists&title_li=&style=');  
  echo '</div><div class="td">'; 
  echo wp_list_categories('taxonomy=list_state&type=user_lists&title_li=&style=');  
  echo '</div><div class="td">'; 
   the_tags('', ', ', '');
  echo '</div><div class="td">'; ?>
  <form class="delete-coupon" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
    <input class="more-button" type="submit"  value="Delete" />
  </form>
  <?php  echo '</div></div>'; ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself.

What i was doing wrong was the query_posts line i had read

```
query_posts( array( 'post_author' => $current_user->ID,'post_status' => 'publish' , 'post_type' => array(    'user_lists' )  ) );
```

And the correct way should be

```
query_posts( array( 'author' => $current_user->ID,'post_status' => 'publish' , 'post_type' => array(    'user_lists' )  ) );
```